# why is my substitution regex only applied to last match

Tags: regex, perl

$ramdetails contains the following:

```
RAM details: 
BankLabel  Capacity    MemoryType  Speed  TypeDetail  
           4294967296  0           1333   128         
           4294967296  0           1333   128
```

when i unleash the following on $ramdetails

```
$ramdetails =~ s|(\d+)(\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+$)|$1/$mbmultiplier."MB   ".$2|ge;
$ramdetails =~ s/(\d{1,2})(\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+$)/$ramtype$2/g;   
$ramdetails =~ s/(\d+)(\s+\d+\s+$)/$1."MHz".$2/ge;

$ramdetails =~ m/(\d+)\s+$/g;                                
$typedetail = $typedetails{$typedetail}; 

$ramdetails =~ s/\d+(\s+$)/$typedetail$1/g;
```

i get :

```
RAM details: 
BankLabel  Capacity    MemoryType  Speed  TypeDetail  
           4294967296  0           1333   128         
           4096MB     Unknown           1333MHz   Synchronous
```

I have no idea as to why only the last match is replaced. i know that my usage of `\s+`  and `\d+` are probably a bit abundant.

note: `$ramtype` is gotten from a hash defined earlier, `$mbmultiplier` speaks for itself i think.

Comment: Use the multiline modifier: `|gem;`, `/gm;`, `/gem;` etc (or `(?m)` within the regex). `$` will match only at the absolute end of the string if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` matches at the end of the string, or before a newline at the end of the string.

You want to add the `/m` modifier to change `$` to match at the end of the string, or before any newlines.